# What is the optimal authorization flow for this usecase?

Tags: authentication, authorization

Imagine that I'm building a server that provides useful APIs for web chat development. I want it to be accessible only to registered developer accounts. A developer registers and builds a chat that uses my API. The chat is anonymous, so chat users are not expected to register anywhere. However the chat uses my API that should not be accessible to just *anyone*. I understand that I cannot just make a developer include some sort of API key in the client code because then it becomes possible to steal it. Then maybe the developer builds his own authentication solution which somehow hides the (secret) API key, but then how am I (the service provider) supposed to know which requests to my API are authorized and which are not? Is there a way for the developer to "share" his rights with the users of his chat?

Comment: This is called DRM and won't work. If you want your API to include authorization, what you actually want to authorize are the end-users. Otherwise, just make a framework like jQuery does.